# Discord Bot setting someones nickname

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord bot and I want to make a !nick command and I keep getting the same error, could someone help me:

ERROR:

```js
{ DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

    at item.request.gen.end (/rbd/pnpm-volume/76d7cd6d-9602-4908-bb55-ccc4f8de8537/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:79:15)

    at then (/rbd/pnpm-volume/76d7cd6d-9602-4908-bb55-ccc4f8de8537/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/snekfetch/3.6.4/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)

    at <anonymous>

    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

  name: 'DiscordAPIError',

  message: 'Missing Permissions',

  path: '/api/v7/guilds/485921672013283339/members/469227202345697280',

  code: 50013,

  method: 'PATCH' }
```

CODE:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = (client, message, args, member) => {
  const arg = args.join(" ")
  if (arg === null || arg === "" || arg === undefined || arg == " ") {
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      embed.setColor(0x00AE86);
      embed.addField("USAGE", "!nick (nickname)", false);
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
  else {
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      embed.setColor(0x00AE86);
      embed.addField("NICKNAME", "You have set your nickname to **" + arg + "**", false);
    message.channel.send(embed);
    message.member.setNickname("["+ member.highestRole.name + "]" + member.displayName)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);
}
}
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error, if so please tell me **HOW** to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From `message: 'Missing Permissions'` we can conclude that your bot is missing the required permissions.

To fix the issue go to your Discord Developer Portal and get the `PERMISSIONS INTEGER` that contains the permissions you need. The most common is `8`, which is the integer for Administrator permissions.

If that doesn't work, ensure that your bot's role is above others in your Discord Server
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohbTh.png)